# Adding every new string to an existing list Of Stings

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am trying to add the `templateFields`' values of my gridview into a `List(Of String)`. Those `templateFields` consist of 2 `Labels`. What I am trying to achieve is

1. To be able to loop through every row of the `GridView`, getting the repetitive templateField values.
2. Store the row's `TemplateFields1` values in a string.
3. Add that string into a list of strings.

Here's my code:

```
For Each row As GridViewRow In GridView1.Rows`
    Dim stri As String
    Dim ttt As Label = DirectCast(row.FindControl("Title"), Label)
    Dim desc As Label = DirectCast(row.FindControl("lblDescription"), Label)
    stri = ttt.Text.ToString & desc.Text.ToString
    Dim list As New List(Of String)
    While (stri <> Nothing) 
        list.Add(stri)  ' Add every new string in a new index of the list 
    End While
Next
```

So in the `while` loop, take `stri` store it in `list(0)` and then continue the `for loop`, get the next `stri` and store it in a new index of `list(1)` while keeping `list(0)` and so on until all `templateField stri` is completed.

Any thoughts or suggestions ?

Comment: You should just move the `Dim List` outside of the `For Each row` loop. You are now making a new list each time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must create the list outside the loop. I'd also replace the `While` loop with an `If` statement:

```
Dim list As New List(Of String)

For Each row As GridViewRow In GridView1.Rows
    Dim ttt As Label = DirectCast(row.FindControl("Title"), Label)
    Dim desc As Label = DirectCast(row.FindControl("lblDescription"), Label)
    Dim stri As String = ttt.Text.ToString & desc.Text.ToString

    If (Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(stri)) 
        list.Add(stri)
    End If
Next
```

Comment: worked but how do I print all the items in that list into a textbox? Is it something like `For i as integer = 0 To list.count - 1  TextBox.text = list.item(i).ToString`?

Comment: @HumamShbib best thing would be to make this a new question here on stackoverflow